# Have the same font for numbers on axis and for axis label in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have the following code to create the plot depicted below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [...]
y = [...]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathsf{Concentration [mol/m^{3}]}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathsf{Diffusion Coefficient [m^2/s]}$')
plt.semilogy(x, y)
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.autoscale()
plt.savefig("coeff.pdf")
plt.show()
```

It's perfectly possible to use LaTeX math notation for the axis label. Unfortunately, the numbers at the ticks/grid lines have another font:

[image: Plot with two different fonts]

**How can I make sure the axis labels and the numbers have the same font and style?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `mathtext` font to the regular font:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'
```

This works for using `mathtext` for equation rendering. If you use Latex, you should take a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html).